# INNER JOIN results in no rows

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have product details in tne table, say `products`, categories and brand names in different tables say `categories` and `brand`. And I want to join these in a query. The query I use is,

```
$sql = "
SELECT p.pid
     , p.name
     , p.slug
     , p.category
     , c.name
     , p.brand
     , b.name
  FROM products p
  JOIN categories c
    ON c.sno = p.category
  JOIN brand
    ON b.sno = p.brand 
 WHERE p.sku=?
";
```

This query does not return any rows. However there are data in products, categories and brand tables.

Is there any logic failure in my query?

Products table

[image]

Categories table

[image]

Brand table

[image]

Comment: There may be data but that doesn't mean that the join keys match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Let me give you a sample data. Will edit the question now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I have shown you a sample data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

For the data that you have shown, your query should work.  I would start by removing the `where` clause and running:

```
SELECT products.pid, products.name, products.slug, products.category, categories.name, products.brand, brand.name
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `categories` on products.category = categories.sno 
INNER JOIN `brand` on products.brand = brand.sno ;
```

(You should run this directly on the database; if there is a lot of data, just throw in a `limit 100` to see if you get anything.)
If this doesn't return anything, then you have a problem with the joins.  Look at the types of the fields.  Are they the same?  If not, fix the data structure.  If they are characters, check for leading spaces and hidden characters.

If that query returns what you expect, the the problem is matching the skus.  The most likely problem is the assignment of the value in php.  Check that this is really doing what you want.  Once again, check for leading spaces in the `sku` column and in the value.  If this is the problem, you can use `trim()` to fix the problem.

Comment: This query works. And instead of `WHERE products.sku` I tried with `WHERE sku=?`, it worked. I am surprised!

Comment: @CroResistor . . . I prefer the query with the table aliases. Perhaps you accidentally fixed some other problem, such as a typo.

Comment: However I am using aliases. I have double checked. `products.sku=?` is not working. I really could not understand. Anyway thank you for the ideas :)